# Is there any method to check Appium android Listview Scrollable property for true or false

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Is there any method in selenium to check scrollable property of android.widget.ListView class. Actually List view is using in my android application & scrollable property set as "false" until element size of list become more than 4.

I am using ScrollToExact method in my code but it does not work when element size is less than 4 with Scrollable false property. I am using following code

```
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
(ListView,ScrollabeView) IOS (UIAScrollableView
WebElement element     =driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ListView"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String widId = ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId();
scrollObject.put("text", "Rewards Redeemed");
scrollObject.put("element", widId);
js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can perform this action by using loop in which first we search by text whether it is visible on screen or not. if it exists than we can perform click operation. if it does not present than we can use scrollTo method to do this operation.

```
List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
if(int i=0; i<=list1.size()-1; i++)
{
if(!list1.get(i).findElements(By.id("id/item_notification")).isEmpty())
{
(list1.get(i).findElements(By.id("id/item_notification"))).click();
break;
}
else
{
driver.scrollTo("id/item_notification").click();
}break;
}
```